# Pipreqs missing optional dependency package requirement

Tags: python, dependencies, requirements, requirements.txt

Most of the time, I use `pipreqs` to generate a `requirements.txt` file so anyone can reproduce the working environment on their side based on that requirements file.

Here I am facing a case where there is a missing package requirement in the file generated by pipreqs, so the code is not running out of the box in a freshly created environment using the `requirements.txt` file.

```sh
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

The missing package is `openpyxl` which is an optional dependency of `pandas`.

```sh
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.show_versions() 

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : 5f648bf1706dd75a9ca0d29f26eadfbb595fe52b
python           : 3.9.7.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 10
Version          : 10.0.19042
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE           : English_Canada.1252

pandas           : 1.3.2
numpy            : 1.21.4
pytz             : 2021.3
dateutil         : 2.8.2
pip              : 21.3.1
setuptools       : 59.6.0
Cython           : None
...                ...
openpyxl         : None          <== HERE!
...                ...
numba            : None
```

Indeed, the content of the generated `requirements.txt` file does not contain `openpyxl`, but contains `pandas`:

```sh
pandas==1.3.2
plotly==5.4.0
```

Is there a way that `pipreqs` could outputs the `pandas` dependencies in the generated `requirements.txt` file so I don't have to enter it manually?

**NOTE**: I know about `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but I don't like that method since it generates requirements based on the installed packages in the environment, which many of them may not be required to run the code.